# Trying to fix a problem with finding neighbors in Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, tkinter, conways-game-of-life

I was trying to recreate Conway's Game of Life in python using Tkinter, but I got stuck while checking for the neighbors. I can't seem to find the solution to my problem.
If a cell is alive it is stored using numpy, 0 for the dead cells and 1 for the living cells. The function "get_neighbours" checks if the cell is not in a corner or next to a side and it returns the ammount of neighbours each cell has. The function "recalculate" basically makes a new board with 0s and 1s which then replaces the original board and redraws everything. But when compared to an already existing game the progress is different.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
win = tk.Tk()

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
vs = 10
absvs = vs
cells = np.zeros((WIDTH//vs, HEIGHT//vs), dtype=int)
cells_new = np.zeros((WIDTH//vs, HEIGHT//vs), dtype=int)

def get_neighbours(x, y):
    total = 0
    if x > 0:
        total += cells[x - 1, y]
    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        total += cells[x - 1, y - 1]
    if y > 0:
        total += cells[x, y - 1]
    if x > 0 and y < (HEIGHT // absvs - 1):
        total += cells[x - 1, y + 1]
    if x < (WIDTH // absvs - 1):
        total += cells[x + 1, y]
    if x < (WIDTH // absvs - 1) and y < (HEIGHT // absvs - 1):
        total += cells[x + 1, y + 1]
    if y < (HEIGHT // absvs - 1):
        total += cells[x, y + 1]
    if x > 0 and y < (HEIGHT // absvs - 1):
        total += cells[x - 1, y + 1]
    return total

def recalculate():
    global cells, cells_new
    for y in range(HEIGHT//absvs):
        for x in range(WIDTH//absvs):
            temp = get_neighbours(x, y)
            if (temp == 2 and cells[x, y] == 1) or (temp == 3 and cells[x, y] == 1):
                cells_new[x, y] = 1
            elif temp == 3 and cells[x, y] == 0:
                cells_new[x, y] = 1
            elif temp < 2 or temp > 3:
                cells_new[x, y] = 0
    cells = cells_new
    canvas.delete("all")
    create_stage()
    redraw_cell()

def slider_changer(e):
    global vs
    canvas.delete("all")
    vs = w.get()
    create_stage()
    redraw_cell()

def create_cell(e):
    global cells
    tx = e.x // vs
    ty = e.y // vs
    x = tx * vs
    y = ty * vs
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + vs, y + vs, fill="gray")
    cells[tx, ty] = 1
    print(get_neighbours(tx, ty))

def redraw_cell():
    for x in range(WIDTH//vs):
        for y in range(HEIGHT//vs):
            if cells[x, y] == 1:
                canvas.create_rectangle(x * vs, y * vs, x * vs + vs, y * vs + vs, fill="gray")


def create_stage():
    for x in range(WIDTH//vs):
        canvas.create_line(x*vs, 0, x*vs, HEIGHT)
    for y in range(HEIGHT//vs):
        canvas.create_line(0, y*vs, WIDTH, y*vs)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()

w = tk.Scale(win, from_=10, to=50, orient="horizontal", command = slider_changer, length = 500)
w.pack()
w2 = tk.Button(win, text = "PRESS ME!!!", command = recalculate)
w2.pack()

create_stage()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", create_cell)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: it works well, so it looks like it is just the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues in your code:

- In `get_neighbours` the last `if` block is the same as the fourth `if` block, and so there is a neighbor that is counted twice and another neighbor that isn't counted at all (the one at `x + 1` and `y - 1`). So replace this:

  ```
  if x > 0 and y < (HEIGHT // absvs - 1):
      total += cells[x - 1, y + 1]
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if x < (WIDTH // absvs - 1) and y > 0:
      total += cells[x + 1, y - 1]
  ```
- In `recalculate` the assignment to `cells` at the end is making you *lose* one of the two arrays. Now both `cells` and `new_cells` reference the very same array<sup>1</sup>. This means the next iteration will not be calculated correctly. Instead, you should *copy* the content of `cells_new` into `cells`. So replace:

  ```
  cells = cells_new
  ```

  with:

  ```
  cells = cells_new.copy()
  ```
- In `recalculate` the `if...elif..elif` construct (inside the double loop) does not deal with the case where `temp == 2 and cells[x, y] == 1` and so `cells_new[x, y]` might not be reset to 0 when it should. In fact, the last part of this construct should not have a condition; it should be a catch-all for all states that the previous checks did not deal with. So replace:

  ```
  elif temp < 2 or temp > 3:
      cells_new[x, y] = 0
  ```

  with:

  ```
  else:
      cells_new[x, y] = 0
  ```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> It is not helping that several websites, including https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-copy-numpy-array-into-another-array/ and https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/numpy/numpy-copy, wrongly assert that an assignment of one numpy array to another makes a copy. That is not true.</sup>